# How to cut a rectangular drawable in semi circle shape ?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need help with cutting a rectangular drawable in a semi circular shape.

I tried using `Path.addArc()` but couldn't get the result required. I could only cut the image in a rectangle.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addArc(rectF, 0, 180);
canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
canvas.drawBitmap(orig, rect, rect, circlePaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method to get circular shape from a rectangle bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    float r = 0;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    } else {
        r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }
    RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, 
            new int[] {0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00FFFFFF},
            new float[] {0.0f, 0.4f, 0.8f}, 
            android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP); 

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setShader(gradient); 
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

and then you can cut the circle into half like this

```
 Bitmap semicircle=Bitmap.createBitmap(circlebitmap, 0, 0, circlebitmap.getWidth()/2 , circlebitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: Bitmap semicircle=Bitmap.createBitmap(target, 0, 0, target.getWidth()/2 , target.getHeight());
  canvas.drawBitmap(semicircle, 0, 0, circlePaint);           This is something i tried but didn't work ...

Comment: well it worked for me. How are you using it..? first send your rectangular bitmap as parameter to the first method. then you get a circular bitmap. And then using createBitmap you can cut the circle into half and you get a semicircle.

Comment: if target is your rectangle bitmap, then    Bitmap circlebitmap=getCircularBitmap(target);   Bitmap semicircle=Bitmap.createBitmap(circlebitmap, 0, 0, circlebitmap.getWidth()/2 , circlebitmap.getHeight());    this should definetly work now.